# Run-length encoding in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compression

I wrote a short Haskell script to compress and decompress via the use of run length encoding.

The concept is simple enough, `n` equal items `x` in a row will be replaced by `(n, x)`, decompressing is just the reverse.

For example:

```
> runLengthCompress "foooo barrr"
[(1,'f'),(4,'o'),(1,' '),(1,'b'),(1,'a'),(3,'r')]
```

As you can see the four consecutive `o` have been substituted by `(4,'o')`

About the code itself I fear I have written too little points (arguments) to my functions, hindering readability but I am not sure, maybe the lack of points makes it more readable, not less.

Also I feel like my `areInverses` function is already built-in into Haskell and that I am rebuilding the wheel with it.

Without further ado, here is the code:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow

runLengthExpand :: [(Int, a)] -> [a]
runLengthExpand = concat . map (uncurry replicate)

runLengthCompress :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
runLengthCompress = (map (length &&& head)) . group

areInverses :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> [b] -> Bool
areInverses f g = all ((==) =<< f . g)

examples :: [[Int]]
examples = [ [3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 1], [1,1,1,0,0,0,5] ]

main :: IO()
main = do
  print $ runLengthCompress "foooo barrr"
  print $ areInverses runLengthExpand runLengthCompress examples
```

Comment: http://lpaste.net/5825040676416389120 - hlint is your friend.
Try quickcheck to get things like your areInverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to import only the functions you're actually going to need:

```
import Data.List     (group)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
```

As Gurkenglas already said, use `concatMap` instead of `concat . map`. This leads to

```
runLengthExpand :: [(Int, a)] -> [a]
runLengthExpand = concatMap (uncurry replicate)
```

Your `runLengthCompress` is fine, although `(&&&)` might not be known to newcomers.

Now, `areInverses` is too obfuscated:

> About the code itself I fear I have written too little points (arguments) to my functions, hindering readability but I am not sure, maybe the lack of points makes it more readable, not less.

Pointfree style isn't [necessarily easier to read](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree):

> #### 5 Problems with pointfree
>
> Point-free style can (clearly) lead to Obfuscation when used unwisely.

We can split its functionality in multiple functions:

```
isInverseOn :: Eq a => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> Bool
isInverseOn f g x = x == g (f x)

areInverses :: Eq a => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> [a] -> Bool
areInverses f g = all (isInverseOn f g)
```

This removes the need for `=<<` completely and is easier to read than your previous `(==) =<< f . g`.

However, that only checks whether `g` is an inverse of `f`, not whether `f` is the inverse of `g`. For example, `g`'s codomain might not be the completely covered by `f`'s domain. So a proper `areInverses` should also check `isInverseOn g f` for some appropriate values.

You can use QuickCheck to generate appropriate strings and lists of pairs, although you need to generate the latter by hand.